# Apache ServiceMix installing bundle OSGI

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I got this message when i was trying to install bundle to apache ServiceMix:

> Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
>           Unable to start bundle mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/shell-sample/1.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved cons
>   traint in bundle shell-sample [235]: Unable to resolve 235.0: missing requirement [235.0] osgi.ee; (
>   &(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))

This is my command:

```
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/shell-sample/1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I don't understand this, google can't give me answer

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
  <artifactId>shell-sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>shell-sample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr311-api-1.1.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1_7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
                        <Import-Package>
                            javax.wsdl,
                            javax.xml.bind,
                            javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                            javax.ws.rs,
                            javax.ws.rs.core,
                            org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
                            org.apache.commons.httpclient,
                            org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.apache.karaf.shell.cxf.jaxrs
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                </configuration>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.apache.karaf.shell.Service</mainClass>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I try to change java version to 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 but still the same error with other java SE version

I am using Eclipse Luna Java EE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The osgi.ee requirement was introduced in maven bundle plugin 2.5.0. So the simplest way to get rid of it is to downgrade to the bundle plugin 2.4.

To change the java language version refered to in the requirement you have to use the maven-compiler-plugin and set the target and source parameters there. You can not change the java version in the maven bundle plugin config.

Comment: I have maven-compiler-plugin in my pom, but what next? Download 2.4  maven bundle plugin ?

Comment: Simply configure the maven-compiler-plugin for java 1.7 and leave the maven-bundle-plugin as is.

Comment: Thank you so much! After that i add org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime 1.0 and evrythink is working!